# Swift -dead_strip doesn't remove unused classes

Tags: swift, static-libraries, static-linking, strip

I create simple static library with only one source file for test -dead_strip option

```
public class UsedClass {
public init() {)
public func function() { print("print") }
}
public class PublicClas {
func private_func() { print("print") }
}
class SimpleClass {
func private_func() { print("print") }
}
public struct PublicStruct {
func private_func() { print("print") }
}
struct SimpleStruct {
func private_func() { print("print") }
}
```

And dynamic library witch use only one class from static library

```
public class MyClass {
public func callModule() {
let qq = UsedClass()
qq.function()
}
}
```

Link dynamic library with option -dead_strip

I see SimpleClass artifact in output binary, use command
nm -m test_lib | grep SimpleClass

```
0000000100003d54 (\__TEXT,\__const) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassC11public_funcyyFTq
0000000100003d5c (\__TEXT,\__const) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassC12private_funcyyFTq
0000000100003d64 (\__TEXT,\__const) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCACycfCTq
0000000100003e58 (\__TEXT,\__swift5_fieldmd) non-external \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCMF
0000000100003a38 (\__TEXT,\__text) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCMa
00000001000083e0 (\__DATA,\__data) non-external \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCMf
00000001000083b8 (\__DATA,\__data) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCMm
0000000100003d20 (\__TEXT,\__const) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCMn
00000001000083f0 (\__DATA,\__data) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCN
0000000100003a6c (\__TEXT,\__text) non-external (was a private external) \_$s13TestFramework11SimpleClassCfD
0000000100008198 (\__DATA,\__objc_const) non-external \__DATA__TtC13TestFramework11SimpleClass
0000000100008150 (\__DATA,\__objc_const) non-external \__METACLASS_DATA__TtC13TestFramework11SimpleClass
0000000100003e24 (\__TEXT,\__swift5_typeref) non-external (was a private external) \_symbolic \____\_ 13TestFramework11SimpleClassC
```

After googling a found that Apple static library is not same with Unix static library, but whats different? I think my example is very easy and all C++ linkers can understand it and remove unused classes

I remove -ObjC option, and try add -internalize-at-link option( from https://forums.swift.org/t/why-public-symbols-are-always-no-dead-strip/47264 ), but always have same result, only private struct removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes in Swift work with the Objective-C runtime (even if you don’t use @objc). They each create a record of an objc class in the app binary. You can find them with code like this:

```objectivec
NSString *executablePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath];
unsigned int classNamesInMainBinaryCount = 0;
const char **classNamesInMainBinary = objc_copyClassNamesForImage([executablePath UTF8String], &classNamesInMainBinaryCount);
```

Since objc supports dynamic features such as `NSClassFromString()` these classes need to stay in the binary and can’t be stripped at compile time.

I work on a tool that detects these kinds of unused classes at runtime, called [Reaper](https://docs.emergetools.com/docs/reaper). This is the only way to really know if they are not used by any of the dynamic runtime features.

Comment: Thanks I was waiting for something like this